# Как защитить свое приложение от взлома?

Tags: android, android-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, я создал несколько приложений для андроид в андроид студии. Как можно максимально защитить свое приложение от взлома и декомпелирования?

Comment: Гугли обфускация кода

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите защитить исходный код, то используйте обфускацию. Например, ProGuard. Думаю этого достаточно, т.к. 100% защиты вам ничто не даст. Эти меры всего лишь усложнят взлом. Другие методы отнимут у вас много времени, но большого прироста процентов от взлома не дадут.

На текущий момент, все сводится к тому, что защита исходного кода ставится от дилетантов.

Если у вас есть конфиденциальные данные в исходном коде, то перемещайте их в веб-сервисы и получайте по мере надобности.